# passing textfield data to another view

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Am trying to pass the text in the text field to another view

here is my code

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var next:itemDetailsView = segue.destinationViewController as! itemDetailsView
        if(segue.identifier == "itemV"){
            next.titleReceived == titleF.text
        }
    }
```

and here how i declared titleF

```
  @IBOutlet weak var titleF: UITextField!
```

titleReceived in the next view

```
var titleReceived:String!
```

there is a button, when i click it, it should take me to the other view, but the app crashes when i put this line of code

```
next.titleReceived == titleF.text
```

Comment: == is  Equality operator  , use = asignment operat for assingning  value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have write double Equuleus in `next.titleReceived == titleF.text` instead of `next.titleReceived = titleF.text` that's why second `view` can't get value.

In second `view` you are forcefully unwrapped the value which is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:-

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "itemV") {
        var next = segue.destinationViewController as itemDetailsView;

        next.titleReceived = titleF.text

    }

}
```

enjoy. its working here